# Optimize Setting Pandas column with Function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a task to create a column in my DataFrame based on the file that was used to create said DataFrame. I can tackle this task with an example of the code below, but I'm thinking there is a better way of doing so. I'm pretty sure I can skip the steps of creating the column and setting it to zero: `dfp['F'] = 0` and could probably make the function a little cleaner.

How would you optimize this code?:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
dfp = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [np.NaN,np.NaN,3,4,5,5,3,1,5,np.NaN], 
                    'B' : [1,0,3,5,0,0,np.NaN,9,0,0], 
                    'C' : ['AA1233445','A9875', 'rmacy','Idaho Rx','Ab123455','TV192837','RX','Ohio Drugs','RX12345','USA Pharma'], 
                    'D' : [123456,123456,1234567,12345678,12345,12345,12345678,123456789,1234567,np.NaN],
                    'E' : ['Assign','Unassign','Assign','Ugly','Appreciate','Undo','Assign','Unicycle','Assign','Unicorn',]})
print(dfp)

file2 = r'desktop\somefolder\foo.txt'
def filename():
    if 'foo' in file2.lower():
        return 'foo'
    elif 'bar' in file2.lower():
        return 'bar'

dfp['F'] = 0
dfp['F'] = dfp['F'] = filename()

print(dfp)
```

PS: I usually read in the dataframe with `pd.read_excel()` hence using a filename in the function. Also using pandas version 0.19.2

Comment: This might be better suited for StackExchange's Code Review community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing this for every row is not necessary.  You can do it once and fill that into an entire column.

Use the `re` module

```
import re


fnames = re.findall('(foo|bar)', file2)
fname = fnames[0] if fnames else None

dfp['F'] = fname

dfp

     A    B           C            D           E    F
0  NaN  1.0   AA1233445     123456.0      Assign  foo
1  NaN  0.0       A9875     123456.0    Unassign  foo
2  3.0  3.0       rmacy    1234567.0      Assign  foo
3  4.0  5.0    Idaho Rx   12345678.0        Ugly  foo
4  5.0  0.0    Ab123455      12345.0  Appreciate  foo
5  5.0  0.0    TV192837      12345.0        Undo  foo
6  3.0  NaN          RX   12345678.0      Assign  foo
7  1.0  9.0  Ohio Drugs  123456789.0    Unicycle  foo
8  5.0  0.0     RX12345    1234567.0      Assign  foo
9  NaN  0.0  USA Pharma          NaN     Unicorn  foo
```

Comment: very very close to what I need! Thank you. in `fname` would there be a way to change `foo` to something else? Let's say `foo` is in file2, but I want my pandas column to say `Program X`?

Comment: Use a dictionary to map it. `fmap = dict(foo='Program X')` Then `dfp['F'] = fmap[fname]`

Answer (score 0):

I maybe missed the point but here is how you can assign filename to column:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
dfp = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [np.NaN,np.NaN,3,4,5,5,3,1,5,np.NaN], 
                    'B' : [1,0,3,5,0,0,np.NaN,9,0,0], 
                    'C' : ['AA1233445','A9875', 'rmacy','Idaho Rx','Ab123455','TV192837','RX','Ohio Drugs','RX12345','USA Pharma'], 
                    'D' : [123456,123456,1234567,12345678,12345,12345,12345678,123456789,1234567,np.NaN],
                    'E' : ['Assign','Unassign','Assign','Ugly','Appreciate','Undo','Assign','Unicycle','Assign','Unicorn',]})
file2 = r'desktop\somefolder\foo.txt'
filename = file2.split('\\')[-1].split('.')[0]
dfp['F'] = filename
print(dfp)
```

Comment: good bit of code, but not what I needed.I appreciate the time!